# Compare two strings and find multiple matches

Tags: php, string, find

I have two strings I want to compare and return the number of occurrences found.

For example.

```
$string = "123,456,789";

$find = "123,657,456";
```

With the right function this should return "2"

I've tried

```
echo substr_count($string,$find);
```

Which returns "0", but if $find = "123" then it will return "1"

I know I could do this if I used a loop and checked each 3 digits seperately but I want to avoid using a loop to allow readability (I'm already using a lot of loops).

If this at all possible with any existing functions or one liners? Or will I have to create my own helper function or loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Easy using arrays:

```
echo count(array_intersect(explode(',', $string), explode(',', $find)));
```

Comment: Awesome, just what I need.
In the case that there is no delimiter, how would I be able to do the same thing?

Comment: @moj If there is no delimeter how do you tell the numbers apart?

Comment: @HankyPanky Well I'm not sure.
The code AbraCadaver provided works perfectly if my find strings are 3 charactors, but sometimes they are two and that won't find anything.

Comment: Why not? This code does not depend upon your string sizes as long as they both contain comma separated values. It will work fine even for 1 or 1000 elements each